# Wireless card kicking out after transporting laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, firmware, wireless-adapter, wireless-card

I have a junker of a laptop. It's an HP ProBook 4510s running Windows 7 Ultimate, with the screen removed.

I had it sitting in the living room, hooked up to my TV via VGA. The internet connection worked fine. Then I moved it to the attic. When I plugged it into a new monitor, the red X next to the wireless icon was showing.

The card is on, the switch on the side of the laptop shows that. Windows Diagnostics cannot find anything wrong.

I tried installing the driver update from HP, no success. I put a fan under the laptop to make sure it wasn't an overheating problem.

The card works for thirty seconds every half-hour to four hours.

Do I need to replace it or is there something software/firmware-wise I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, "I moved it to the attic" implies it's now out of range of your WiFi router. Try another laptop to see if the signal is too weak. If that is the issue, then there are a number of things to improve the range:

1. [Try channels 1, 6 and 11](http://www.metageek.com/training/resources/why-channels-1-6-11.html) if you're in the 2.4 GHz band for best range.
2. Adjust the router antenna(e).
3. If you can access the laptop's WiFi adapter, add a [cantenna](http://www.instructables.com/id/Fast-Cheap-and-Easy-Wifi-Cantenna/).
4. Move the WiFi router.

Second, if you **can** get a good signal on another laptop *in the attic*, and believe the one in your old laptop is broken or not sensitive enough, try [an external USB WiFi adapter, available for $US10 or less](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M08W63E). Even some"micro" adapters have surprisingly good range, but opt for one with an external antenna, if it's far to the router.

Comment: Hmm... my phone could connect just fine up there, but when I moved the laptop to the garage it had one or two issues before connecting fine for hours. I think I misinterpreted the red X next to the wireless icon... thanks.